# Firebase/Firestore/React - what stops a user from adding a million fields to their own user document?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm coming from a SQL background, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the whole schemaless concept.

I think I got the jist of it, and I get the benefits of it - but if you have a frontend layer that has access to a Firestore DB, what stops the user from adding *anything* to the documents they have rights to write to?

I've looked at a lot of different React/Firebase/Firestore examples now, and they all seem to gloss over it - so maybe I'm missing something very obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what stops the user from adding anything to the documents they have rights to write to?

Aside from your [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) that validate that the document data being written, the only limit that is impossible to bypass for a single document with write access is the [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits) of the size of a single document: 1MB.  You can read more in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size).

If you don't have any rules that restrict what data can be written to a document, this size is the only limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
I guess it's just a bit of a mindblow to me to have a database 'open' like that?
Like.. surely a malicious user would be able to do.. something... bad? or maybe not?

maybe i'm just too burnt from all the scary SQL injection ghost tales?

Comment: The most important part of Doug's answer was "security rules" - FOLLOW THAT LINK.  A database is *most assuredly* NOT open unless you deliberately *set* the security rules so it *is*.  One major difference in SQL injection is that "data" can contain characters that confuse a string-type SQL statement. Firestore (and NoSQL in general) DO NOT USE such an approach, so are less vulnerable to *that* attack.

Comment: All databases are effectively "open" if there is some sort of API that allows reading and writing of data through that API.  Firestore is no different.  If you want to allow access through the API provided by the SDK, then you should protect that access using security rules.  If you don't want to use security rules, then write your own API and protect in any way you want.